# JTextPane is going out of boundary from JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

```
chatTextPane = new JTextPane();
chatTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,150));
//chatTextPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350,150));//new
scrollingTextPane = new JScrollPane(chatTextPane);
scrollingTextPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollingTextPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
//scrollingTextPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350,150));
```

I'm writing a chat program on JDialog. My JTextPane is going out of boundary from the JDialog. I have added two pictures. One is before closing the JDialog window and the other is after opening the JDialog window again.

Comment: I'm new user and they didn't allow me to upload pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `chatTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,150));`.  It's prevent it from telling the `JScrollPane` how big it should be.

Take a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more reasons why you should avoid using `setPreferredSize`...just in case your mistake this time didn't make it clear ;)

Comment: I removed chatTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,150)); Now chatTextPane is really really small. You can barely see it. How can I set the size?? I tried setSize(new Dimension(350,150)); but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, normally, I'd use a layout manager.  But, `JTextPane` is one of those annoying components which doesn't allow you to change the "preferredScrollableViewportSize` value, which is actually based on the components `preferredSize` ... not good.  In your case, you may have no choice but to set the preferredSize of the `JScrollPane` instead...not what I'd prefer, but I can't see a better solution...

Comment: I got it....I set scrollingTextPane..setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,150)); ......It works now... thanks anyway